# Accordion buttons won't toggle in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I am having issues getting a simple JavaScript for accordion style buttons to work. I copied the code directly from this [example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp). I have followed a video tutorial parts [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4xbvhXj72kU) and [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ocFvfCG5-Nc), as well as [Using JavaScript](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript) at the WordPress Codex.

Here is accordion.js

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        /* Toggle between adding and removing the "active" class,
        to highlight the button that controls the panel */
        this.classList.toggle("active");

        /* Toggle between hiding and showing the active panel */
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
        }
    });
}
```

Here is functions.php

```
<?php
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'hestia-style'; // This is 'hestia-style' for the Hestia theme.

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
?>

<?php
function hestia_child_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'accordion js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/accordion.js');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'hestia_child_scripts' );
?>
```

Here is my HTML

```
<button class="accordion">Are there minimums?</button>
<div class="panel">
   <p>We accept orders of any size.</p>
</div>
```

The link to accordion.js is being generated because I can see it in the source.

Comment: What issue exactly you are getting. Is it throwing error or just not working? and please make sure also your js in including

Comment: It's just not working. When the button is clicked, nothing happens, the text remains hidden.

Comment: Make sure your js is including

Comment: can you paste the HTML also

Comment: have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: I believe my JS is included. Under, "Here's is accordion.js". Please, excuse me if I entered the wrong code, I'm very new at this.

Comment: ProEvilz I am getting an error on several objects, including accordion.js: "This site makes use of a SHA-1 Certificate; it’s recommended you use certificates with signature algorithms that use hash functions stronger than SHA-1." I created this certificate when transferring my site to a local host for testing. Is this the cause?

Comment: Your goal should be *zero errors* on the console :)

Comment: brasofilo lol that makes sense ;)

Comment: why don't you try by adding js manually in footer

Comment: Make sure your JS is being added after html load, You can do that by `$(document).ready()` or load your Js in footer section

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code in local sever and it is working fine. So there can be some possibilities why your code is not working

1. Either your JS is not including or it is throwing error which you can check in console <sup>[[1]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) [[2]](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/)</sup>
2. Or some of your divs is overriding the accordion so you're not able to click on it and it is not working. So it can be a HTML,CSS issue

So please be sure to check these points.

Comment: I'm pretty sure JS is being included because I did a test with a simple, alert("hi"); and it worked fine with no errors. But when I use the accordion code I get an error that reads: 'Use of Mutation Events is deprecated. Use MutationObserver instead. jquery.js:3:9644'. I'm not really sure what it means or how to get rid of it. I've researched it some but the solutions were  confusing, as I'm a beginner. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Update: Also getting this 'TypeError: panel is null'. On this line, `if (panel.style.display === "block") {`

Answer (score 0):

Try to enqueue your script like this:

`wp_enqueue_script( 'accordion js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/accordion.js', array(), null, true);`

it ensures that the script is loaded after page load and can find the element you are targetting on page i.e. `.accordion`

Comment: Sorry, this didn't work. But I am getting a TypeError: panel is null on this line `if (panel.style.display === "block") {`. Do you know what might be causing it?

Comment: panel is null means, your JS code is unable to find DOM node with class 'panel'. If you use jQuery, try enclosing your code in jQuery(document).ready(function(){});